# PostgreSQL - implicit transactions analogue

Tags: postgresql, transactions, stored-functions

I am using PostgreSQL 10 from RDS (AWS).
So note that I don't have full permissions to do whatever I want.

In PostgreSQL I have some functions written in PL/pgSQL.

From my experience in these function I cannot start/commit/rollback transactions. In a `DO` block I cannot do that either.

Is that correct? So what is the logic behind this... seems PostgreSQL expects each function to be called in the context of an existing transaction. Right?

But what if I want every statement in my function to be executed in a separate (short) transaction i.e. to have a behavior something like AUTOCOMMIT = ON?

I found some extension which maybe can do that but I am not sure.
I don't know if it's relevant.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html

Isn't there a standard way of doing this in Postgres without the need to download and install additional packages/extensions?

Again: I want every statement in my function to be executed in a separate (short) transaction i.e. to have a behavior something like AUTOCOMMIT = ON.

So I want something like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

All statements in a function run in the same transaction, and no plugin can change that.

You can use procedures from v11 on, but you still have to explicitly manage transactions then.

I suspect that the best thing would be to run your functions on the database client, where you have autocommit automatically, rather than as a function in the database.